# Combining values across columns and pyspark and pivoting

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have a pypark df like so:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|kurtosis_1m|kurtosis_2m|kurtosis_3m|kurtosis_4m|kurtosis_5m|kurtosis_6m|
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|3688539|  99725|     6.7484|     6.2753|     6.2055|     7.2076|     7.0501|     7.5099|
|3689076|  99705|     4.8109|     4.3774|     4.1131|     4.4084|     4.1568|     4.4445|
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to pivot it in such a way that I end up with a dataframe like so:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|kurtosis   |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|3688539|  99725|     6.7484|
|3688539|  99725|     6.2753|
|3688539|  99725|     6.2055|
|3688539|  99725|     7.2076|
|3688539|  99725|     7.0501|
|3688539|  99725|     7.5099|
|3689076|  99705|     4.8109|
|3689076|  99705|     4.3774|
|3689076|  99705|     4.1131|
|3689076|  99705|     4.4084|
|3689076|  99705|     4.1568|
|3689076|  99705|     4.4445|
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

I figured one way would be to create the `kurtosis` column as an array column and then exploding it. How do you combine the values of columns across a dataframe into a single column as an array.
I have other columns like `mean_1m`, `mean_2m` etc... that I need to pivot in the same manner.
Any insights?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?module-pyspark.sql.functions#pyspark.sql.functions.array) to combine multiple columns into one array and then - like you have already described in your question - [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?module-pyspark.sql.functions#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the array.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [x for x in df.schema.names if "kurtosis" in x]

df.withColumn("kurtosis", F.explode(F.array(cols))) \
    .drop(*cols) \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|kurtosis|
+-------+-------+--------+
|3688539|  99725|  6.7484|
|3688539|  99725|  6.2753|
|3688539|  99725|  6.2055|
|3688539|  99725|  7.2076|
|3688539|  99725|  7.0501|
|3688539|  99725|  7.5099|
|3689076|  99705|  4.8109|
|3689076|  99705|  4.3774|
|3689076|  99705|  4.1131|
|3689076|  99705|  4.4084|
|3689076|  99705|  4.1568|
|3689076|  99705|  4.4445|
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: the ```if string in x``` picks up all words with the letters. How do I get it to pick exact word? For example ```if 'UL' in x``` picks up columns with the names `UL` and `MUL` I only want it to pick `UL`

Comment: @thentangler replace the `in` with a `==` as you would do in a normal if condition. Some examples can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

You can **create an array of dataframes and union them**.

First, identify the `kurtosis` columns:

```
sub_string = "kurtosis"
kurtosis_col = [x for x in df.schema.names if sub_string in x]
```

Now create an array of dataframes equal to the number of `kurtosis` columns:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_array = [df.withColumn('col', F.concat(F.col(x)))
                .select('seq_id', 'tool_id', 'col') for x in kurtosis_col]

# Union them
reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_array).withColumnRenamed("col", "kurtosis").show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| seq_id|tool_id|kurtosis|
+-------+-------+--------+
|3688539|  99725|  6.7484|
|3688539|  99725|  7.2076|
|3688539|  99725|  6.2753|
|3688539|  99725|  6.2055|
|3688539|  99725|  7.5099|
|3688539|  99725|  7.0501|
|3689076|  99705|  4.4084|
|3689076|  99705|  4.1131|
|3689076|  99705|  4.8109|
|3689076|  99705|  4.4445|
|3689076|  99705|  4.3774|
|3689076|  99705|  4.1568|
+-------+-------+--------+
```

You can follow a similar approach for your other set columns like `mean_1m`, etc. One way to join them back and to avoid duplicates is by using `row_number()` and `monotonically_increasing_id()` before joining. Let me know if you need that piece of code.

Comment: I think using the inbuilt pyspark `array` function, might be easier. 
Thank you for your solution Cena. I really appreciate it!